# How to remove forwarding timestamp? OSE version Syslog-NG

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, syslog-ng

Following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28833774/3317808),

I have tried making changes in Syslog-NG 3.17 [OSE version](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.17/administration-guide/tzoffset-c_tzoffset-r_tzoffset-s_tzoffset), with below configuration,

```
@version: 3.17

@include "scl.conf"

options {
};

source s_network_to_forward {
        network(
                flags(no-parse)
                transport(udp)
                port(514)
                keep-timestamp(no)
                persist-name("somekey")
        );
};


template forward_template {
        template($RAWMSG);
        template_escape(no);
};

destination forward_to_syslog2{
        network("1.2.3.4" transport(udp)  port(514) template(forward_template));
};

log {
        source(s_network_to_forward);
        destination(forward_to_syslog2);
};
```

---

Message to forward: `Oct 31 16:44:29.071 UTC: %SYS-3-DUP_TIMER: Same tty2 in linewatch_timers, type 2`

Above configuration is able to forward the message as shown below(with extra header in bold):

**Oct 31 12:44:29 X.X.X.X 5277586:** `Oct 31 16:44:29.071 UTC: %SYS-3-DUP_TIMER: Same tty2 in linewatch_timers, type 2`

where X.X.X.X is showing actual sender address(as expected), process id(`5277586`) and forwarding timestamp(`Oct 31 12:44:29`)

but

expecting to forward only `Oct 31 16:44:29.071 UTC: X.X.X.X 5277586: %SYS-3-DUP_TIMER: Same tty2 in linewatch_timers, type 2`

by removing forwarding timestamp

---

How to forward the required format?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forward the message as it was sent, the `$RAWMESSAGE` macro is a good idea, but by default it is empty (as it makes a message memory footprint larger).

You have to add an extra flag `flags(...,store-raw-message)` in the source configuration. (see the related [documentation](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.17/administration-guide/flags))

Your configuration would look like something this:

```
@version: 3.17

@include "scl.conf"

options {
};

source s_network_to_forward {
        network(
                flags(no-parse,store-raw-message)
                transport(udp)
                port(514)
                keep-timestamp(no)
                persist-name("somekey")
        );
};


template forward_template {
        template("$RAWMSG");
        template_escape(no);
};

destination forward_to_syslog2{
        network("1.2.3.4" transport(udp)  port(514) template(forward_template));
};

log {
        source(s_network_to_forward);
        destination(forward_to_syslog2);
};
```